# fancybox for images in rails not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fancybox

I'm trying to display all the images in a page and when clicked on each image it has to enlarge, so for that, I have used fancybox. But the code is not working. I'm new to rails, could anyone help me out to solve this issue?

```
_images.html.erb code:
<div class="center" id="images" style="padding:50px 50px 50px 50px;">
<table>
<% @images.each_slice(4) do |images| %>
  <tr>
    <% images.each do |images| %>
      <td style="padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;"> 
        <%= link_to image_tag images, id: '#images', class: "fancybox" 
      ,:size => "300x300" %><br />
      </td>
     <% end %>
    </div>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
 </table>
</div>

/* fancybox code */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Comment: are you getting any error at browser console?

Comment: have you setup fancybox code properly ?

Comment: The title is very misleading. fancybox works regardless of whether you are using ruby, php or whatever. Simply make sure you are generating correct html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this as it mentioned in  [doc here](http://fancybox.net/howto)

also make sure `images` (so if you are using paperclip carrierwave then it should be `image_url`) variable is image link, and on `link_to` it expects bigger image than with `image_tag`

```
  <% images.each do |image| %>
    <%= link_to image_url, class: 'fancybox' do%>
      <%= image_tag image_url(:thumb), id: 'images', :size => "300x300"%>
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
```

Comment: I tried adding that code, but when the image is clicked it says that the requested content cannot be loaded.

Comment: @SushmaKv so can you see the images before click it?

Comment: Yes, I can see. All the images are displaying but when I click on it to view it is not loading

Comment: @SushmaKv  remove the `class: 'fancybox'` from image tag an try it like this: -- 
`<%= image_tag image_url(:thumb), id: 'images' :size => "300x300"%>`

Comment: By adding this it gives some                                                             
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' image_url(:thumb), id: 'images' :size => "300x300");

Comment: @SushmaKv sorry my mistake forgot to add comma (,) after `id: 'image'` so this should be `<%= image_tag image_url(:thumb), id: 'images', :size => "300x300"%>`

Comment: @SushmaKv by the way id should be dynamic of each image, you should not provide common id more than one time on one html page. so if @images is active record object then you can provide id like this: - `id: "<%=image.id%>"` replace with `id: "images"`

Comment: with that change, it tells that "thumb" is not present in the asset pipeline.

Comment: @SushmaKv exactly. i'm not sure what if you are using paperclip or carrierwave gem to store image or are you storing image for two different size? so for now here you can only provide `image_url` instead of `image_url(:thumb)` for testing it. so like this:
`<%= image_tag image_url, id: 'images', :size => "300x300"%>`

Comment: I have used carrier wave gem. For the change, you suggested now doesn't work it gives wrong no argumnets

Comment: @SushmaKv so i m not sure how are you getting image's url , so basically point is to provide url of image inside image_tag block. so alternatively you can use `image.url` instead of `image_url`.

Comment: It got solved by doing like this                                                         
 <%= link_to image_url(images), class: 'fancybox' do%>
      <%= image_tag images, :size => "300x300" %>
  <%end%>                                                                                            thank you soo much for your help :)

Comment: @SushmaKv cool !! so your fancy box is working now, feel free to accept/upvote answer for future Stackoverflow searcher. and let me know for further guidance

Comment: Ya sure. Thanks !!

Comment: @SushmaKv can you accept the answer if it helped you?